# c# webbrowser viewer control takes time to dispose

Tags: c#, pdf, webbrowser-control

When closing Form containing a WebBrowser control with a Pdf document open in the webbrowser, the form takes some 10 seconds to close. I tracked the issue down to Dispose method of the webbrowser.

```
private void advBandedGridView1_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.FocusedRowChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (advBandedGridView1.GetFocusedDataRow() != null)
        {
            string wordno = advBandedGridView1.GetFocusedDataRow()["wordno"].ToString();
            string itemcd = advBandedGridView1.GetFocusedDataRow()["itemcd"].ToString();

            for (int i = 0; i < _caseCount; i++)
            {
                ButtonColoring(wordno, _seqkindCode[i]);
            }

            LoadPDF(itemcd);

            gridControl2.DataSource = null;
            gridControl2.RefreshDataSource();
        }
    }
```

Control Event

```
private void LoadPDF(string itemcd)
    {
        try
        {
            ReturnPacket rp;

            rp = new Q3i.POP.BIZ.Common.CommonCode().SelectCommonCodeFull("603", "kind3 = 'EYE'", false);

            if (rp.DataTables.Count > 0 && rp.DataTables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                rp = new Q3i.POP.BIZ.Common.CommonCode().SelectCommonCodeFull("603", "kind3 = '1'", false);
            }

            if (rp.DataTables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string dockind = string.Empty;
                dockind = rp.DataTables[0].Rows[0]["code"].ToString();

                ParameterCollection paramCol = new ParameterCollection();
                paramCol.Add("p_itemcd", itemcd);
                paramCol.Add("p_dockind", dockind);
                PdfFileInfo temp_fileInfo = biz.SelectInspectionStandards(paramCol);

                if (temp_fileInfo != null)
                {
                    if (_fileInfo != null && temp_fileInfo.FileNm == _fileInfo.FileNm)
                    {
                        WebBrowserPdf.Visible = true;
                        return;
                    }

                    _fileInfo = null;
                    _fileInfo = temp_fileInfo;

                    PDF_FILE_PATH = FilePath + _fileInfo.FileNm;

                    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(FilePath);
                    if (di.Exists == false)
                    {
                        di.Create();
                    }

                    if (!File.Exists(PDF_FILE_PATH))
                        File.WriteAllBytes(PDF_FILE_PATH, _fileInfo.FileData);

                    if (!PDF_FILES.Contains(PDF_FILE_PATH))
                    {
                        PDF_FILES.Add(PDF_FILE_PATH);
                    }

                    WebBrowserPdf.Navigate(PDF_FILE_PATH + "?#zoom=" + _zoomFactor + "%", false);

                    WebBrowserPdf.Visible = true;
                    simpleButtonOpenPOPUP.Enabled = true;                        
                }
                else
                {
                    WebBrowserPdf.Visible = false;
                    simpleButtonOpenPOPUP.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UCXtraMsgBox.ShowDialog(ex.Message, "m0146", Q3i.Common.Enums.MsgBoxButton.OK, Q3i.Common.Enums.MsgBoxIcon.Alert, true);
        }
    }
```

it is Load Method

```
private void w_pcmu081_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            WebBrowserPdf.Dispose();

            Process[] Pro = Process.GetProcessesByName("osk");
            if (Pro.GetLength(0) > 0)
                Pro[0].Kill();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            UCXtraMsgBox.ShowDialog(ex.Message, "m0146", Q3i.Common.Enums.MsgBoxButton.OK, Q3i.Common.Enums.MsgBoxIcon.Info, true, null, true);
        }
    }
```

Closing

Comment: Have you tried disposing `WebBrowser1`?

Comment: I tried two methods. WebBrowser.Dispose(true), and Form Close()

Comment: Put `WebBroswer.Dispose` inside `Form1_FormClosing` event handler.

Comment: I tried that, but there was no difference.

Comment: Share the code.

Comment: That's it.
I also added the Dispose () syntax to the closing event.

Answer (score 0):

The same situation happened to me.
Adobe has done something wrong in the latest version of Acrobat Reader DC (15.023.20056).
If you uncheck option **Enable Protected Mode at startup** in Edit -> Preferences -> Security (Enhanced),  everything will be back to normal.
On my case it is not a solution.

More info here: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2267688